# Is there a specific date format that needs to be inserted in Sqlite db DateTime column?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to insert a datetime value into a sqlite table, however the value that's inserted is
"YYYY-01-DD08:01:SS"

```
{ "NextSyncDate", task.NextSyncDate.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") }
```

Is there a way to insert am/pm as well in sqlite table's datetime field? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all letters should be uppercase inside `ToString`. Try like:

```
ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

capital `MM` is month where as lowercase `mm` is minutes. Capital `HH` is 24 hours format, where as if you write lowercase `hh` is 12 hours format

Answer (score 2):

This has NOTHING to do with SqlLite and is a basic C# question.

The following is the string you execute to get the timestamp:

.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")

This is totally C#. It also is totally incorrect.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

explains all components you can use and guess what - the first one (YYYY) is already not on the list. The C# version is "yyyy" - small. And as some are there in MM and mm (minute and Month) - you basically create garbage.

Hint: next time use debugging. GRAB THE STRING - then it would be obvious that the output of that ToString makes no sense.